# accessing i2c device through windows application

Tags: c#, c, visual-c++

I am testing HID-I2C compliant device on windows 8. The device is connected over I2C interface 
but there is no interrupt line from our our I2C device to the x86 Machine.

Is there any way i can still enumerate my HID-I2C device ?

From the msdn website i came to know that for HID-I2C enumeration the HID-I2C class driver reads the Device information from ACPI table.

Is there any way to re-enumerate HID-I2C devices from a user application ?
code sample of any such application can help me a lot.